# Which is the best clustering algorithm for clustering multidimensional data with low density difference?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-science, k-means, dbscan

I am working on a project currently and I wish to cluster multi-dimensional data. I tried K-Means clustering and DBSCAN clustering, both being completely different algorithms.

**The K-Means model** returned a fairly good output, it returned 5 clusters but I have read that when the dimensionality is large, the Euclidean distance fails so I don't know if I can trust this model.

**On trying the DBSCAN model**, the model generated a lot of noise points and clustered a lot of points in one cluster. I tried the KNN dist plot method to find the optimal eps for the model but I can't seem to make the model work. This led to my conclusion that maybe the density of the points plotted is very high and maybe that is the reason I am getting a lot of points in one cluster.

For clustering, I am using 10 different columns of data. ***Should I change the algorithm I am using? What would be a better algorithm for multi-dimensional data and with less-varying density?***

Comment: Hi. The question is reasonable, but [cross-validated site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is probably more suitable for this kind of questions and you'll get the answer there faster. Stack overflow is more about general software development, then machine learning.

Comment: Okay thanks! I will check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first make a dimension reduction on your dataset with PCA/LDA/t-sne or autoencoders. Then run standart some clustering algorithms.

Another way is you can use fancy deep clustering methods. This [blog post](https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-do-unsupervised-clustering-with-keras/) is really nice explanation of how they apply deep clustering on the high dimensional dataset.

Comment: I thought of giving PCA a try but didn't really do it. I'll try your suggestions. I just have a small doubt, it might be a little dumb but does dimension reduction in PCA mean elimination of dimensions?

Comment: PCA uses an orthogonal transformation to convert your features into linearly uncorrelated features. So PCA creates new principle components(new features instead of your old ones) which are the mixes of your features. You can specify component number(your new dimension size).

Comment: could you please accept the answer, if it works for you to help for others.

Comment: I know I am a little late to mark your answer as the correct one. I took some time to understand PCA and t-SNE but I finally feel satisfied. I paired PCA with t-SNE where I used PCA for dimension reduction and t-SNE to visualize results from different Clustering programs. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this provides you with some inspiration: [Scikit-learn clustering algorithms](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html)
I suggest you try a few out. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! it does give the use cases for different algorithms, I'll check it out. Any suggestions of your own for my problem?

Comment: If K - Means doesn't deliver satisfying results, I'd suggest affinity propagation, agglomerative clustering or spectral clustering.